# SQL Server CTE Recursing too many times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I need some help figuring out the best way to build this query, and I think I've decided that a CTE is the best idea. I am open to other suggestions if there might be a better way.

This application has several different object types. A simple hierarchy of the objects I'm currently concerned with is the following: `Group -> Catalog(s) -> Item(s) and Feature(s) -> Features (items also connect to features) -> Feature Values`. Each of these objects are also versioned, so they could be the first version, or several versions deep. (This hierarchy is just provided for understanding of what is trying to be accomplished.

The data that I'm going after is all contained in a `History` table. The table has the following columns: `HistoryID, HistoryObjectID, HistoryObjectCode, HistoryObjectTypeID, HistoryMessage, HistoryObjectTypeObjectID, Timestamp, ParentHistoryID, ParentObjectID, HistoryObjectGuid, NetworkID`

- HistoryObjectID is an ID that is foreign keyed to whichever object table the row is created from (like Group, Catalog, etc.)
- HistoryObjectCode is another identifier from the object table and is used in the UI
- HistoryObjectTypeID is an enum that corresponds to the type of Object (i.e Group, Catalog, etc.)
- Message should be self-explanatory
- HistoryObjectTypeObjectID (bad name) is the primary key of the object
- Timestamp - self-explanatory
- ParentHistoryID - filled if this history record "spawned" from another. We're actually not really using this right now.
- ParentObjectID - this is the current column being used in the CTE. This is filled with the primary key of the "parent" of the object. This is defined as either the primary key of the parent version of the object if there is one. If this version is the first version, then it's the primary key of the parent object. So for a first version of a catalog this is filled with the Group ID in which the catalog is contained.

Here's what I currently have for a query. My problem is that the recursion happens for every row that is returned in the "base case":

```
WITH n(HistoryID, HistoryObjectID, HistoryObjectTypeID, HistoryObjectTypeObjectID, HistoryObjectCode, HistoryMessage, UserID, Timestamp, ParentHistoryID, ParentObjectID, HistoryObjectGuid) AS (
    SELECT HistoryID, HistoryObjectID, HistoryObjectTypeID, HistoryObjectTypeObjectID, HistoryObjectCode, HistoryMessage, UserID, Timestamp, ParentHistoryID, ParentObjectID, HistoryObjectGuid 
    FROM [DBName].[History] 
    WHERE HistoryObjectID = @HistoryObjectID
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT nplus1.HistoryID, nplus1.HistoryObjectID, nplus1.HistoryObjectTypeID, nplus1.HistoryObjectTypeObjectID, nplus1.HistoryObjectCode, nplus1.HistoryMessage, nplus1.UserID, nplus1.Timestamp, nplus1.ParentHistoryID, nplus1.ParentObjectID, nplus1.HistoryObjectGuid
    FROM [DBName].History as nplus1
    INNER JOIN n on n.HistoryObjectTypeObjectID = nplus1.ParentObjectID) 
  SELECT n.HistoryID, n.HistoryObjectID, n.HistoryObjectCode, n.HistoryObjectTypeID, n.HistoryMessage, n.HistoryObjectTypeObjectID, n.Timestamp, n.ParentHistoryID, n.ParentObjectID, n.HistoryObjectGuid, u.NetworkID
  FROM n INNER JOIN [CatalogBuilder].[User] u on n.UserId = u.UserId
```

For example, one of the following runs of the query with a certain ID results in 1653 rows being returned, and there are 28 rows returned in the base case. If I add a `distinct` in the final select statement, I only get the 49 rows I am actually interested in. The obvious problem is this query takes an extremely long time to run due to the unnecessary recursion.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to do this is a better way.

**EDIT: Adding sample data**

Desired results (14 rows returned):

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| HistoryID | HistoryObjectID |   HistoryObjectCode   | HistoryObjectTypeID |                   HistoryMessage                   | HistoryObjectTypeObjectID |          Timestamp          | ParentHistoryID | ParentObjectID |          HistoryObjectGuid           |       NetworkID        |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|    313404 |          572668 | TEST CATALOG CREATION |                   3 | Created catalog version 1.0.0 for catalog TESTCAT  |                       201 | 2019-01-04 15:02:22.1533333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319335 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Updated Catalog code to CATALOGCODE                |                       201 | 2019-01-23 21:29:19.6933333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319538 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Set English description to "new desc edited"       |                       201 | 2019-02-04 18:32:11.2166667 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319539 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added ADP to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-04 18:32:14.3100000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319544 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added USD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-05 13:36:11.5433333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319551 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added CAD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-06 14:35:28.9100000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319552 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added USD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-06 14:35:28.9700000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Too many rows returned (56 rows):

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| HistoryID | HistoryObjectID |   HistoryObjectCode   | HistoryObjectTypeID |                   HistoryMessage                   | HistoryObjectTypeObjectID |          Timestamp          | ParentHistoryID | ParentObjectID |          HistoryObjectGuid           |       NetworkID        |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|    313404 |          572668 | TEST CATALOG CREATION |                   3 | Created catalog version 1.0.0 for catalog TESTCAT  |                       201 | 2019-01-04 15:02:22.1533333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319335 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Updated Catalog code to CATALOGCODE                |                       201 | 2019-01-23 21:29:19.6933333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319538 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Set English description to "new desc edited"       |                       201 | 2019-02-04 18:32:11.2166667 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319539 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added ADP to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-04 18:32:14.3100000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319544 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added USD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-05 13:36:11.5433333 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319551 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added CAD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-06 14:35:28.9100000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319552 |          572668 | CATALOGCODE           |                   3 | Added USD to Catalog                               |                       201 | 2019-02-06 14:35:28.9700000 | NULL            | NULL           | 3CE6BD8D-3AF4-46D2-9004-976113E110CD | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319685 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created Item TESTITEM8 - 1.0                       |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:49.8633333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319686 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English name to "Test item #8"                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:54.0033333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319687 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Created item version 1.0                           |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:32:56.8800000 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319688 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Set English description to "Test Item Description" |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 15:33:00.4266667 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319689 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Set English name to "test"                         |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.6400000 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319690 |          585465 | NEW-FEATURE-CREATION  |                   6 | Created feature version 1.0                        |                     19224 | 2019-02-11 16:27:33.9066667 | NULL            | 201            | 55ACDB43-51E6-4A5D-94DB-8B0808F946D6 | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
|    319692 |          585464 | TESTITEM8             |                   4 | Linked feature NEW-FEATURE to item                 |                     52051 | 2019-02-11 18:59:17.2133333 | NULL            | 201            | FB3D799F-2038-4CE1-A27E-0C6F6EBE607F | hmiedema@steelcase.com |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

It appears the "extra" rows are being returned for every run of the base case. There are 7 rows returned in the base case, and 49 rows from the other 7 entries, which should be unique and is where the ending 14 rows desired would come from (7 from base case + 7 other unique rows).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (You're using one in the CTE).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited and fixed the query. Seems like a pretty subjective fix to me, and I only had one table and made sure it was in my where clause, but edited nonetheless.

Comment: I don't understand the problem:  Why are you only interested in 49 of the 1653 rows being returned?   Why would `Distinct` eliminate the rows you don't want?   Do you have duplicates in your table?   Why isn't the solution to put `distinct` in the top query in your CTE?

Comment: It still makes things much clearly, especially when your CTE is only called `n`; I honestly missed the reference at first. On the subject of your problem, a rCTE only processes each row once, which means there's something else here. Sample data and expected results might help here.

Comment: Added sample data of a smaller example, and a bit of an explanation

Comment: The ones labeled "desired results"

Comment: So where is your sample data? Expected Results != Sample Data.

Comment: I'm confused. The second set of data is what happens when I run the query. The first set is when I run it without `distinct`. This is sample data.

Comment: So, if `DISTINCT` gives you the answer you want, what is the question here? We have 2 of the 3 following things: Sample Data (What your data looks like from a `SELECT *`), Expected Results (What you want your data to look like), Undesired Results (What the data you're receiving from your query looks like). There can't be an overlap of these. From your description, we have Expected and Undesried, so we need your sample data so we can help you get from A to B. Getting from Z to B doesn't help you, when you're at A.

Comment: I believe that your problem is here: `INNER JOIN n on n.HistoryObjectTypeObjectID = nplus1.ParentObjectID` instead of `HistoryObjectTypeObjectID` it should be `HistoryObjectID`

Comment: The query takes minutes to run when the data grows, even when distinct is on, because there is some sort of issue with the way I'm doing my recursion

Comment: That doesn't actually work @LuisCazares. It only gives me the 7 rows returned from the base case. Those two columns don't line up correctly.

Comment: Now I see. Your ParentObjectID doesn't point to a unique key. That's a problem with recursion. Try changing to [a set-based loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/set-based+loop/127670/).

Comment: I'm a little confused by the similar column names.  Are you sure you have the correct columns in the join in the CTE?  Should it be HistoryObjectId = ParentObjectId?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LuisCazares. I am taking a look, but a bit confused. In the "set-based loop" section of your article, what's the point of setting `OriginalGroupId` and `OriginalMemberId` in the `UPDATE g SET` statement? I don't really understand what that is doing since those aren't used again.

Comment: @dougp I know it's somewhat hard to follow and understand without knowing the data. `HistoryObjectID` and `ParentObjectID` will never be the same, though. `HistoryObjectID` is set by a sequence, and `ParentObjectID` is a primary key of the object that the history is referring to.

Comment: @LuisCazares nevermind, I think I follow now.